# Cox Proportional hazard model - Comparing coefficients from sub datasets

Tags: r, comparison, cox-regression, cox

I am doing a study of credit risk in europe for the period of 2006 - 2016 by using the Cox Proportional Hazard Model (time costant edition) in R (coxph). I have succesfully implemented the model for the whole period with 8 independent variables.

Now I want to make 2 subgroups (2006 - 2010 and 2011 - 2016) in order to compare the coefficients between the two subgroups. I have created a dataset of the sub groups by with a dummy variable so that 2006 - 2010 = 0  and 2011 - 2016 = 1.

What is the next step in the analysis in order to compare the coefficents in the two sub groups?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: First, you may want to provide data. Second, this may be a question better suited for Cross-validated, which is a sister-site of stackoverflow. Third, you should use the new dummy variable as a factor.

Comment: Dear Akash 

Thank you for your reply

What do you mean using the new dummy variable as a factor? 

Thank you ind advance

Comment: <https://www.openintro.org/download.php?file=survival_analysis_in_R&referrer=/stat/surv.php> This website is something i have referenced in the past.